# running a jar file from command prompt

Tags: jar, command-prompt, beanshell

so i have stored my jar file in C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\jre\lib\ext

is the following command correct:

```
Java -cp C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\jre\lib\ext\bsh-2.0b4.jar
```

It does not seem to run the jar file

PS: please provide helpful notes instead of simply downvoting the question, i'm still new to this site. thanks.

Comment: did you try running directly C:>C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\jre\lib\ext\bsh-2.0b4.jar

Comment: running my original command gives me a lot of options like `-jrockit -classpath -agentlib` etc...nothing is launched

Comment: @Satish running it directly like you mention returns that is not recognized as an internal or external command, operaable program or batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search for "running a jar file command line" yield this link (http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip127.html) saying to run this command:
`java -jar myjar.jar`

Running `java -help` yields more information, and online documentation will explain all your command-line options to you (such as [Oracle's java command documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)).